# Proof convergence for $a_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I am trying to do a proof for convergence. But I am stuck in my proof not getting any further...  What is missing to finish that proof?

$$a_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$ 
Show that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$$

Let $e > 0$ and $\forall n \ge n_0 = \lceil \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\rceil+1 \in \mathbb Z^+:$

$\begin{align}
|a_n-0| &\equiv |a_n| \\
&\equiv | \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}|\\
&\equiv|\frac{1}{(n+1)} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)}| \\
&\equiv |\frac{1}{n+1}| \cdot |\frac{1}{n+1}| \\
&< |\frac{1}{n}| \cdot |\frac{1}{n}| \\
&(\text{because } n \in \mathbb N) \\
&=  \frac{1}{n^2} < \epsilon \text{ (by definition of convergence) }
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
n \ge n_0 &= \lceil \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\rceil +1 \\
&> \lceil \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \rceil \\
&\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}
\end{align}$

thus

$\begin{align}
n &> \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \\
&\equiv \frac{1}{n} > \sqrt{\epsilon} \\
&\equiv \frac{1}{n^2} > \epsilon
\end{align}$

But the line that should follow:

$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n^2} &< \epsilon
\equiv \frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align}$

which is wrong..

Comment: \begin{align}
n &> \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \\
&\equiv \frac{1}{n} < \sqrt{\epsilon} \\
&\equiv \frac{1}{n^2} < \epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: and then the proof is finished? @MyGlasses

Comment: Yes. with "Show that" you have found $N=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. We need to find $n_0$, such that 
$$
\left|\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-0\right|<\varepsilon
$$
for all $n_0\leq n$.

Set $n_0=\lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil$. Note that if $n_0\leq n$, then 
$$
\left|\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-0\right|=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\leq\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{n_0}=\frac{1}{\lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil}
\leq\frac{1}{1/\varepsilon}=\varepsilon
$$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

You are working too hard.

Look for a simpler upper bound before computing an $\epsilon$.

Note that if $n \ge 1$ then $0 \le a_n = {1 \over (1+n)^2} \le {1 \over 1+n} \le { 1\over n}$.

Choose $n \ge \max(1, {1 \over \epsilon})$.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing way too much here.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0} < \epsilon$ (note that we used the archimedian property of the real numbers here!)

Then, for $n \geq n_0$, we have:

$$\left|\frac{1}{(n+1)²}\right| = \frac{1}{(n+1)²} \leq \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n_0} < \epsilon$$

Hence, we have shown that $$\frac{1}{(n+1)²}\rightarrow 0$$

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

And one more:

$|a_n| = |\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}| \lt |\dfrac{1}{n^2}| \le |\dfrac{1}{n}|.$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.

There is a $n_0$ such that $n_0 \gt 1/\epsilon.$
(Archimedes).

For $n \ge n_0 :$

$|a_n| \lt |\dfrac{1}{n}| \le \dfrac{1}{n_0} \lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about squeezing methods? Since $$0<a_n$$ 
You can show that the limit of the sequence is "trapped" between $0$, which only means it's equal to zero. Now, since
$$n+1>n$$ then
$$\frac{1}{n+1}<
 \frac{1}{n}$$
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$
Take in count here we're using only natural numbers, so these inequalities hold (otherwise, they don't necessarily do). 
Therefore: 
$$0<\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 0\le \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\le\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$0\le \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\le0 $$
Which necessarily implies that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$$
If you're looking for a proof involing the limit definition, I think you've already got a useful bunch.